# Obtain position-specific value from a table with intervals

Tags: r, intervals

I have a table with 3 columns, indicating the beginning and end of each interval, together with a rate in all positions within the interval.

```
| Start    | End            | Rate  |
| -------- | -------------- | ----- |
| 1        | 2              | 2.0   |
| 3        | 5              | 4.2   |
| 6        | 9              | 1.8   |
| 10       | 16             | 1.2   |
```

I would need to expand it, to obtain a table that indicated the rate for each specific position, such as:

```
| Position | Rate           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 2.0            |
| 2        | 2.0            |
| 3        | 4.2            |
| 4        | 4.2            |
| 5        | 4.2            |
| 6        | 1.8            |
| 7        | 1.8            |
| 8        | 1.8            |
| 9        | 1.8            |
| 10       | 1.2            |
```

and so on.

Since the number of positions is high (30 million), I wonder if there is a fast way to do the conversion from range to specific positions, assigning the correct rate to each one. One that does not consist on an endless if loop that checks the belonging of a certain position to each interval.

Is there a way to transform the original table to get something resembling the second one?

Thanks in advance for the help, and apologies for not providing any preliminary code for it. I really have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much to all of you for the fast replies :) The different methods worked perfectly fine and make it very easy to solve the issue I was facing with the intervals.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[, .(Position = Start:End, Rate = Rate), .(id = 1:nrow(df))]
```

gives

```
    id Position Rate
 1:  1        1  2.0
 2:  1        2  2.0
 3:  2        3  4.2
 4:  2        4  4.2
 5:  2        5  4.2
 6:  3        6  1.8
 7:  3        7  1.8
 8:  3        8  1.8
 9:  3        9  1.8
10:  4       10  1.2
11:  4       11  1.2
12:  4       12  1.2
13:  4       13  1.2
14:  4       14  1.2
15:  4       15  1.2
16:  4       16  1.2
```

or `dplyr` option using `unnest`

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Positions = list(Start:End)) %>%
  unnest(Positions) %>%
  select(Positions, Rate)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 16 x 2
   Positions  Rate
       <int> <dbl>
 1         1   2
 2         2   2
 3         3   4.2
 4         4   4.2
 5         5   4.2
 6         6   1.8
 7         7   1.8
 8         8   1.8
 9         9   1.8
10        10   1.2
11        11   1.2
12        12   1.2
13        13   1.2
14        14   1.2
15        15   1.2
16        16   1.2`
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Start = c(1, 3, 6, 10), End = c(2, 5, 9, 16),
    Rate = c(2, 4.2, 1.8, 1.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! setDT worked wonderfully and it is super straightforward. I really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map2` to create sequence between `Start` and `End` columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  transmute(Position = map2(Start, End, seq), Rate) %>%
  unnest(Position)

#   Position  Rate
#      <int> <dbl>
# 1        1   2  
# 2        2   2  
# 3        3   4.2
# 4        4   4.2
# 5        5   4.2
# 6        6   1.8
# 7        7   1.8
# 8        8   1.8
# 9        9   1.8
#10       10   1.2
#11       11   1.2
#12       12   1.2
#13       13   1.2
#14       14   1.2
#15       15   1.2
#16       16   1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this method?

I did it without for loop:

```
df =matrix( c(1,2,2,3,5,4.2,6,9,1.8,10,16,1.2), byrow = T, ncol=3)

g= function(e){
  x= rep(e[3], (e[2]-e[1]+1))
return(x)
}
res = cbind(1:df[nrow(df),2],as.numeric(unlist(apply(df,1,g))))
colnames(res)=c('position' ,'rate')
```

the output:

```
     position rate
 [1,]        1  2.0
 [2,]        2  2.0
 [3,]        3  4.2
 [4,]        4  4.2
 [5,]        5  4.2
 [6,]        6  1.8
 [7,]        7  1.8
 [8,]        8  1.8
 [9,]        9  1.8
[10,]       10  1.2
[11,]       11  1.2
[12,]       12  1.2
[13,]       13  1.2
[14,]       14  1.2
[15,]       15  1.2
[16,]       16  1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `rowwise` with `summarise` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  summarise(Position = Start:End, Rate, .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 x 2
   Position  Rate
      <int> <dbl>
 1        1   2  
 2        2   2  
 3        3   4.2
 4        4   4.2
 5        5   4.2
 6        6   1.8
 7        7   1.8
 8        8   1.8
 9        9   1.8
10       10   1.2
11       11   1.2
12       12   1.2
13       13   1.2
14       14   1.2
15       15   1.2
16       16   1.2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Start = c(1, 3, 6, 10), End = c(2, 5, 9, 16), 
    Rate = c(2, 4.2, 1.8, 1.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```